# large size data transfer from intent service to UI

Tags: android

In my project i need to transfer large size data recieved  via network operation in intentservice to uithread or any other thread.

I am just wondering which will be the best option for this ,it seems i cannot use  parcelable or bundle due to large size of data.And the size is not predictable

it will helpful if anyone suggest an idea  or example which handles  this type of cases.

Comment: binary data or somehow parsable(json or xml)?

Comment: parse it and store data in sqlite, then use it from there ... Content Provider will be even better, because with CP you should not worry about multithreading

Answer (score 2):

you can write the data to a file and pass the file path back

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Application object from the Intent Service and other activities as well. So you create your own subclass of the android.app.Application (don’t forget to register in the manifest) and communicate through this class (e.g. pass the data to this class and check from other thread).